# Proper use of Observable (RxJava)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, rx-java, observable, rx-android

I am already using `RxJava` + `Retrofit` + `EventBus`. It works great!

But I'am not fully understand how to use Rx `Observable` as simple `AsyncTask`.

I wil explain a bit:

For example i have a method, which i want to do in background( not in UI thread):

```
    public void teachMe() {
      for(int i=0;i< daysUntilGenius;i++){
            Log.e("WORK DAY" , String.valueOf(i));
          }
    }
```

When this method will be completed i want switch to main thread and show toast or something else.

Using AsynсTask i can do it simply with methods `doInBackground` and `onPostExecute` , but i want to do it using Rx `Observable` and `Subscriber`.
I alredy used Schedulers,so i know how to switch between threads , i just don't know how to put all of my this together and make it work!

I need and example or snippet of code with a little bit explain, thanks!

Comment: See http://blog.danlew.net/2014/10/08/grokking-rxjava-part-4/

Comment: @zsxwing if it not hard to you, please post snippet of code according to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly i found solution:

```
public Subscription test(final int days){
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super Void> subscriber) {
            teachMe(days);
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }

    })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(),"COMPLETE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Void aVoid) {
                }
            });
}


public void teachMe(int days) {
  for(int i=0;i< daysUntilGenius;i++){
        Log.e("WORK DAY" , String.valueOf(i));
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
public void doAsyncStuff(int days) {
    Observable
        .just(days)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .doOnEach(n -> teachMe(n))
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(n -> Log.i("Completed " + n));
}

public void teachMe(int daysUntilGenius) {
    for(int i = 0; i < daysUntilGenius; i++){
        Log.e("WORK DAY", String.valueOf(i));
    }
}
```